# bwt suffix array construction

Tags: bwa

I found [a very good link](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/3510/57) to generate bwt suffix array in BW based tools.

@user172818 provides a nice code. could anyone tell me how to store SA elements' original position in the original string?